# How to save post data in firefox?

Tags: firefox

I want my posts to be saved (except content of files I upload).

After I used plugins provided by Izzy, I think it must have 2 features:

- Long-time storage for **posted** text
- Short-time for edit history for the case something goes wrong and the text gets deleted before posting.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like howtos, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185).

Comment: Well, if it may require additional software - or maybe not, where should I ask it?

Comment: In that case you were right here – but should read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and [edit] your post accordingly. If your entire question fits into one line, that usually indicates you've missed something :) Here e.g. you're probably looking for an Addon. But where should it save that data (files, internal database)? Only the data you've really posted, or all data you've entered in forms (so in case FF crashes, you don't have to type everything again)?

Comment: "But where should it save that data (files, internal database)?" - doesn't matter, show me at least anything.

Answer (score 2):

For quite a while I've used **[Lazarus](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/)** for this kind of task. That's an addon for Firefox which saves everything you type into forms, and keeps a history – so even a crash wouldn't make your input "done in vain", as you can restore that once Firefox has been restarted:

> Lazarus securely auto-saves all forms as you type, so after a crash, server timeout, or whatever, you can go back to the form, right click, "recover form", and breathe a sigh of relief.

*Lazarus* saves its data into a local SQLite database (in your profile folder). It even keeps a history, so you've got multiple entries to chose from when you've filled a form more than once:

[image: Lazarus] [image: Lazarus options]
<sup>Screenshots of *Lazarus* (source: [Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the right screenshot shows, you can even have passwords excluded from this (for security purposes) – or have them included (if you don't care); if you're paranoid, you can even password-protect the entire database. And you can configure how long saved information should be kept (keep in mind the database can get quite huge when chosing a too large interval here, which then also might slow down your browser in general).

As a final word I've got to admit I've not used Lazarus for quite a while. However, it worked great when I did – on Windows as well as on Linux machines.

---

If you're looking for an alternative, there's also **[Form History Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/form-history-control/)** doing a comparable job:

> - Manage form history entries (search, edit, cleanup, export/import) and easy text formfiller.
> - Auto-save text entered in any form while typing to allow fast recovery when disaster strikes.
> - Control for which webpage form history is saved or not.
>
> An extension to View and Manage all form data that has been saved by the web browser giving you full control over what is stored, what is cleaned up or not, and when to perform a cleanup. This extension even allows you to control selectively for which webpages form history data is stored (either blacklist or whitelist). Also stores text from editor fields as you type for easy recovery in case of disaster.

Other than *Lazarus*, this addon even allows you to browse and edit your form history.

[image: Form History Control] [image: context menu]
<sup>*Form History Control* screenshots (source: [Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/form-history-control/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I've never used this addon, but its ratings are excellent. The choice is yours.