# How to screenshot a menu?

Tags: windows, screenshot

Software to screenshot a menu under Windows. Normally pressing `PrintScreen` causes the menus to disappear.

I don't have any other special "hard requirements".

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like howtos, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185). A hint, though: Windows might not give "visual feedback" on that, but it copied the screenshot to your clipboard. You can then insert it into another application, e.g. a picture editor or Word document.

Comment: I suggest rephrasing your question as "What software will allow me to take screenshots of menus under Windows"

Comment: @Izzy I search for software, including built-in. Steve Barnes offfered a manual, and I would accept it if it was not a workaround for certain cases.

Comment: If you're looking for software, your post is lacking details: what are your requirements? Should it e.g. be capable of a) copy the entire scrren b) selected window c) selected section (to be drawn with your mouse) d) repeat last selection? Do you e.g. need a) annotation features (and if yes, to what degree) b) direct-upload features (e.g. to Imgur or wherever), c) …? You know what comes now: Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and [edit] your question accordingly ;)

Comment: The Print Screen button works fine for me, the menu doesn't disappear, and it copies an image to the clipboard (on Windows 7). What version of Windows are you using, and what software do you want to screenshot?

Comment: @vclaw windows xp, is it really different on windows 7?

Comment: It's currently not explicitly stated in our guideline – but you've seen what happens if you miss it, and your question somehow "looks too short": it creates the impression that you *simply forgot* to mention your requirements, and/or your question will be closed as "too broad". Plus a lenghty list of comments to clarify things, which can definitely be avoided (see the queue here, and [the other question I've referred to](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21015/185)). It's a thing of manner, and to show your effort taken – especially if your question text is short (3 lines or less).

Answer (score 2):

If it is a normal menu, (rather than a context menu), then pressing & holding alt while pressing the menu keyboard short-cut, (usually the initial letter but underlined while you have alt pressed), then without releasing alt press the print screen button.  You will then get a screenshot of the window complete with menus on your clipboard - if you would like just the menu then you will need to edit with any picture editor, e.g. [Gimp](http://gimp.org).

[image: PySolFC]

Comment: It works, but... It's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

[Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) can do that. It doesn't dismiss menus.

Greenshot also has a fairly decent image editor and one click upload to Dropbox and Imgur etc[image]